# How to use the forked repo and still track updates from the original source

Tags: git, github, pip

1. You find a github-based awesome library you want to use.
2. You need to modify the library a bit for your taste. (ok you fork the library)
3. You want to get the update as easily as possible. (increment the pip version as you normally would for the unmodified library?)

What's the best setup to achieve #2 and #3? ie, modify but stay updated as easily as possible.

I'm listing Burhan Khalid, Dan's answers as I understood them.
Thank both for kind answers!

1. local submodule
   git clone the library (as a submodule), and modify as I see fit.
   pull the change of the library when you need it.
2. github fork + local submodule
   you can directly change the code and still manage your changes to the library in a separate repo.
   (not sure about the benefit, you can have the git-forked repo in github so you can make a pull request to the original repo I guess)
3. (github fork +) local clone (as a standalone git repo) + `pip -e`
   The idea is, ok.. it's good to install via pip, isn't it?
   Since pip-installed code lives in virtual-env directory (not neccessarily included in your project repo), it's a pain to make the modification to it and commit it to your git repo.
   (I'm trying to understand what `pip -e` does and what `python setup.py install` does exactly. but it's not as easy as you think Burhan. Thanks though!)

   - I'm not sure if I can specify `pip install from git repo the latest commit availbale` in my requirements.pip
4. `pip -e original library repo` + `python setup.py install`
   You don't care about `pull request` just make modification and use it.
   Not sure what `python setup.py install` does, and how the modification I make will be reflected in my project repo

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a basic Git how-to question which has nothing to do with Python in particular.

Assuming you've `git clone`-d the library into a local repository, then `git pull` will fetch remote changes and then merge them into your local changes.

In many cases, what you really want to do is `git pull --rebase` which will "replay" your local changes on top of the remote changes.

Here's a pretty good blog post introducing the different ways you might want to sync your local repository with the remote source: http://blog.mikepearce.net/2010/05/18/the-difference-between-git-pull-git-fetch-and-git-clone-and-git-rebase/

Comment: Let me make sure If I understand you correctly. Git clone the original library(A) into my local repository(B) (I guess as a submodule?). git-fork the library(A) and make modification in my local repo(C). merge the modification(C) into the local repository(B)

Comment: My instructions assume that you are you are interacting with the original repository via `git` (the command line tool). Are you actually using GitHub's **web interface**?

Comment: I'm using git command, except I'm told git-fork is github only thing, so there's no command for it. (so basically I'll have to git-fork A into A', and to make modification I'll have to clone it to my local machine repo C)

Comment: `git` itself doesn't care what you do with a repository once you've cloned it, whereas GitHub is sort of a "social network for code" that creates a link between the fork and the original forked repo. What you want is the `git clone` command to make a local copy of the original repository. Every GitHub repo has a sidebar showing the URL to use with `git clone`.

Comment: Oh. so I don't need the 'git-fork' stuff here. I always thought `in order to make modification of github based library, I need to fork`. So you are saying, git clone library, make modification to it, and keep updated by git-merging from the origin. I now see what you are saying. Since the library will be part of our code, it will be included into our repository as a submodule I guess. Why do people fork then? to request a pull request?

Comment: In order to modify a GitHub repository /on GitHub/ without permission to commit to it, yes, you need to fork it. This has nothing to do with `git` per se. By design, `git clone` makes a totally independent copy of an existing repository; after cloning, there's no further dependence on the original repo, except when you explicitly interact with it (`pull`, `merge`, etc.)

Answer (score 4):

@Dan is correct that your question is really about git.

A fork is a completely detached copy, and when you clone from your fork on github, your clone (the repository on your desktop) does not know where your github repo was forked from. For it, your github repository is the 'origin'.

So, its often good practice to add the original source as an additional remote with `git remote`.

You won't have rights to write to it, but you can pull and then rebase (which is a fancy way of saying "bring me up to date, by replaying all the commits since I forked or branched"), making sure you are updated with the original, and more importantly if you decide to make a pull request, you haven't broken anything.

For pip specifically, you can have pip [directly pull from github](http://pip.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/pip_install.html#examples):

```
pip -e git://github.com/you/your_fork.git
pip -e https://github.com/you/your_fork.git
```

---

> So what you are suggesting is.. create a fork in github. git clone it
>   into local machine. make modification to it and commit/push to the
>   repo. when I need updates from the original library repo, I should
>   merge those changes into my local forked repo. commit it. Then I can
>   do `pip -e from my forked github repo` again. Sorry if this is rather
>   long but that's exactly why I wanna ask, if there is a shorter way.

This is the correct workflow - if you want to maintain your own version of the original library with some changes.

Although what you should really do is raise a pull request describing your changes (especially if you are fixing some bugs). This way, if your changes don't break anything - there is a chance the original library owner will merge *your* fork into the main repository.

This doesn't mean that the cheese shop (pypi) will be updated, because the original library owner would still have to update pypi "manually" (pypi is not linked or synchronized in any way with git or any other system, it just a store). Once they do that though, then everyone will be able to directly fetch install your modifications.

When you do `pip -e` it installs an [`e`ditable version](http://pip.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/pip_install.html#editable-installs) which means you can play around with it before you actually install it as a package.

If your change is very minor one-time change, you can just install the editable version from the original library source, modify it, then `python setup.py install` your modified version; you can optionally create a patch which you can use to modify the original source if/when the original source updates.

`pip install -e` is really there for installing development versions of packages, because you should not release these on pypi.

Comment: So what you are suggesting is.. create a fork in github. git clone it into local machine. make modification to it and commit/push to the repo. when I need updates from the original library repo, I should merge those changes into my local forked repo. commit it. Then I can do `pip -e from my forked github repo` again. Sorry if this is rather long but that's exactly why I wanna ask, if there is a shorter way.

Comment: Can I modify the `pip -e git://github.com/you/your_fork.git` installed code directly so that I can push it back to the github repo?

Comment: pip -e will not clone a repo, it just pulls the source from git (think of it like downloading the zip); so you won't have a git repository, just a directory of files.

Comment: Say you are making a modification to the library in the context of your application as you test your app. You make the same modification in your other copy (which is git-cloned). Then merge in the modification via `pip -e ...` again. I find it awkward

Comment: You don't "merge" using `pip -e`, you can only merge using git. So, unless your modifications are under version control, there is no way for you to easily apply your modifications should the original library be modified. That's the whole point of putting it under git. `pip -e` is just there as a convenience for those that are testing libraries on git that are not available on pypi yet. You can just `python setup.py install`

Comment: I meant "merge" in a broader sense (my bad!), I could `pip -e` latest version or specific commit hash probably? (if so, I can just update my requirements.pip in my repo so that it points to the latest commit hash) I don't understand your other suggestion for shorter way. `pip -e ` install, modify it, `python setup.py install`: Is the `pip -e` installed code git-controlled (in my project git repository)?

Comment: See the documentation (linked in my answer) to what `pip -e` does exactly.